# duplicate key error when mapreduce with {out: {reduce:coll, sharded: 1}} and MR post processing failed

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, sharding

Good day everybody!

QUESTION: (Sharded MongoDB) mapReduce operation returns:

MR post processing failed: { result: { db: "repu", collection: "stat" }, chunkSizes: [ { _id: MinKey }, 5759761 ], errmsg: "exception: insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: repu.stat.$*id*  dup key: { : "B1000028748293459927" }", code: 11000, ok: 0.0 }

with multiple similar warnings found in Mongod log (all before return of MR command):

warning: ClientCursor::staticYield can't unlock b/c of recursive lock ns:  top: { opid: 141587, active: true, secs_running: 1, op: "query", ns: "repu.stat", query: { $msg: "query not recording (too large)" }, client: "92.36.25.144:57829", desc: "conn2", connectionId: 2, locks: { ^: "W" }, waitingForLock: false, msg: "m/r: reduce post processing M/R Reduce Post Processing Progress: 14779/22241 66%", progress: { done: 14779, total: 22241 }, numYields: 0, lockStats: { timeLockedMicros: { r: 0, w: 158575 }, timeAcquiringMicros: { r: 0, w: 30179 } } }

Exactly the same task is successfull when running in single Mongod (2.6.1) with no sharding. But is fails when running on 3-shard cluster (all shards are running at one windows 7 computer).

CONTEXT OF THE QUESTION:

1) We are running constantly repeating jobs of incrementally updating "stat" collection from (externally populated) "inpu" collection via mapReduce(). Jobs are similar to http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-incremental-map-reduce/

2) map() applied to "inpu" collection emits some "uid" keys (custom almost random 20-chars strings such as "B1000028748293459927"). These should be reduced and become the "_id" keys of target "stat" collection.

3) "inpu" collection is sharded by "uid" key (properly indexed, and enabled with "uid" as the shard key)

4) target "stat" collection is automatically indexed by "_id" and automatically sharded by "_id" as shard key. This sharding is enabled as the result of mapReduce call with
{out : {reduce: "stat", db: "repu", sharded: true}}

5) Repeated jobs are constantly running with steps
- remove() data from "inpu" (but leave indexes as is)
- populate "inpu" with bulk inserts of new data portion (may contain some already seen "uid", and some new)
- run mapReduce() on "inpu" with reduced output to "stat"
- (eventually report something from "stat")
- and iterate from remove() again.

6) Jobs are initiated from Java application (Java Driver: mongo-java-driver-2.12.0.jar),
Fragment of Java code calling to mapReduce is:

```
        BasicDBObject cmdo = 
            new BasicDBObject( "mapReduce", "inpu" )
            .append("map", mapFcn)
            .append("reduce", reduceFcn)
            .append("out", 
                new BasicDBObject("reduce", "stat")
                .append("db", "repu")
                .append("sharded", true)
                )
            .append("scope", scope);

        // Setup optional finalize function
        if (null != finalizeFcn) {
            cmdo.append("finalize", finalizeFcn);
        }

        // Execute MapReduce
        Logger.getGlobal().info("MapReduce sharded (inpu to stat) started");
        CommandResult out = db.command( cmdo );
        Logger.getGlobal().info("MapReduce done: [OK = " + out.ok() + "] "
                + collinpu.getCount() + " to " 
                + collstat.getCount() + " records");
        Logger.getGlobal().info("Error message: " + out.getErrorMessage() );
        Logger.getGlobal().info("Results: " + out.toString() );
```

All *.js functions ( mapFcn, reduceFcn, and not used finalizeFcn ) are plain String 's read from text files.

7) mapReduce returns "half"-populated "stat" collection, with almost 50% of "_id" missing,
when compared with set of initial "uid"-s. This "stat" collection is useless, and we can't logicaly "rollback" unsuccessful mapReduce()-s (due to elaborated "compressing" nature of our reduce() algorithm).

8) We can't use aggregation framework, due to complicated reduce() algorithm.

9) Same task succesfully runs, when using just one standalone Mongod server. In this case nothing is sharded, and all js scripts and mapReduce() are running well.

10) Not all mapReduce() jobs in the processing loop are failed. Some of them run sucessfully (even after some previous failed). The whole problem is "half-solved", which is worse than not being solved at all.

OUR PAIN: 
So, what we are doing wrong, and why some "_id" in output collection are trying to remain "duplicate" (instead of being correctly reduced, as they did in non-sharded case)?

Regards,
Serge Terekhov

Comment: In addition, the following fail assertion found in logs:  

assertion 13388 [repu.stat] shard version not ok in Client::Context: version mismatch detected for repu.stat, stored major version 5 does not match received 4 ( ns : repu.stat, received : 4|3||539c69eefdd4c2ff01d4f63a, wanted : 5|0||539c69eefdd4c2ff01d4f63a, send ) ( ns : repu.stat, received : 4|3||539c69eefdd4c2ff01d4f63a, wanted : 5|0||539c69eefdd4c2ff01d4f63a, send ) ns:repu.$cmd query:{ count: "stat", query: {} }

Comment: have you tried the just released 2.6.2 - there were several map-reduce related bugs that were fixed in it.

Comment: Just installed 2.6.2, started form empty database. The error is still there. Couple of mapReduced did well, then starting from 3-rd call, the signalling error appeared again: Results: { "serverUsed" : "Krasnov:40000" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "MR post processing failed: { result: { db: \"repu\", collection: \"stat\" }, chunkSizes: [ { _id: \"n008\" }, 15368370 ], errmsg: \"exception: insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: repu.stat.$_id_  dup key: { : \"n1001018955025200865\" }\", code: 11000, ok: 0.0 }"}
New error in server log:

Comment: 2014-06-18T17:34:00.500+0400 [Balancer] moving chunk ns: repu.inpu moving ( ns: repu.inpu, shard: shard0000:ANRIN-PC:30100, lastmod: 1|1||000000000000000000000000, min: { uid: MinKey }, max: { uid: "a1055894295427685878" }) shard0000:ANRIN-PC:30100 -> shard0001:ANRIN-PC:30101
2014-06-18T17:34:00.500+0400 [Balancer] moveChunk result: { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "migration already in progress" }
2014-06-18T17:34:00.500+0400 [Balancer] balancer move failed: { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "migration already in progress" } from: shard0000 to: shard0001 chunk:  min: { uid: MinKey } max: { uid: "a1055894295427685878" }